# General pattern for WCF/Web API request and response messages structure

Tags: json, wcf, asp.net-web-api

We have a Web API service of our own which in turn calls the third party WCF web service.

I'm trying to come up with a pattern where we get a response from WCF within which there will be response.status and response.errorDescription. Based on these properties we will translate in to user friendly error messages. This message then will need to be passed on to client via Web API or Controller/Action.

Wondering if there is already a pattern to pass response status and message to client.

Also should all WCF web service must return the response status so that client can look at this status first and process the data? What's the best practice pattern here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over third party WCF their contract will need to be adjusted to send response the way you want it.

We have got many services running which has the same pattern. To our clients we expose the contracts like this.

```
..............................................
[OperationContract]
ResponseType GetData (string request)

..............................................

[DataContract]
public class ResponseType
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Status {get;set;}
  public string ErrorDescription {get;set;}
}
```

now when clients get the response, they can look for status and ErrorDescription.

This is one pattern which is mostly recommended.

There is another way you can do it which is not recommended and is complex. That is by creating a WCF Extension that intercepts the response and converts to a meaningful result.

Comment: Thanks, what about the actual data and also same pattern applies for web api that returns json?

Comment: yes, it's up to you to make decision on that. since web api is flexible to implement, you can implement this pattern on Web Api controller and make it return that response